# Symfony2: Same route path for 2 actions

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, routes

Is it possible to have the same route path but for 2 different actions. I want to use an action when the user is logged in and another when the user isn't logged in.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="bundle_index")
 * @Template("NameBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
 */

/**
 * @Route("/", name="bundle_index_auth")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @Template("NameBundle:Default:auth.html.twig")
 */
```

Comment: I don't think so; symfony will fire the first rout action always. I would recommend to use a variable in your rout like `* @Route("/{isset_var}", name="bundle_index")` and handle it through the action so that if it's not set do first things otherwise second things; or even set the path to ANONYMOUS user in access control section then in your action handle it if the user is not authenticated do first things otherwise second things

Answer (score 0):

Use the same path with different names I think not, and I can't imagine in which cases this could be useful even if we can do it (maybe if you explain better what you want to achieve), but looking your example you can do all the checks you need inside the same action... checking if the ROLE_USER is granted to the user (otherwise redirect the user or throw an access exception whit the same behavior of your example) and rendering the properly template consequently (obviously with any other manipulation needed).

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, having an action and checking if the user is logged in then redirecting him to the proper action. But I feel like it adds garbage in the url for the user. I would like for the user to see only the `http://www.mywebsite.com/` whether he is logged in or not but when he is logged in he doesn't see the same page. Anyway, like I said I've already implemented the solution but I was still wondering.

Comment: But the action where you check the user where did it comes from? I hope it's not coming from a login action isn't it? Otherwise you can use the same path using different http methods like for CRUD operations (GET for the access and POST to check the credentials) At first look This sounds very similar to a "remember me" action... (obviously is already implemented in symfony). Have you thought to a `Listener` or an `Event`?